# What is the root cause of "The RelatedEnd cannot be returned by this RelationshipManager" exception in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.3

I am using Entity Framework 4.3.1 from an ASP .NET MVC 3.0 web application and I have a little bit of code that detaches an old object and replaces it with a new object that looks like so:

```
public void UpdateUnattached(T entryToUpdate, T updatedEntry)
{
    var ctx = (EntityFrameworkContext) _context;           
    ctx.ChangeObjectState(EntityState.Detached, entryToUpdate);
    _set.Attach(updatedEntry);       
    ctx.ChangeObjectState(EntityState.Modified, updatedEntry);
}
```

This works all the time except for one case when I get the exception below on the `_set.Attach` line.

> The RelatedEnd cannot be returned by this RelationshipManager. A RelatedEnd can only be returned by a RelationshipManager for objects that are either tracked by the ObjectStateManager or that implement IEntityWithRelationships.

The object graph is pretty deep and I think it is telling me that there is a property that has been set to an object that has not been change tracked somewhere (please correct me if I am wrong).  So, my question is...

**How do I find out what the root cause of this exception is?**

I have tried putting a try/catch around it and calling `GetValidationErrors` in the catch but that also throws with the same exception.

More information from the exception (`InnerException` is null)...

```
Type: System.InvalidOperationException 
Source: System.Data.Entity 
Target site: GetRelatedEndInternal 
Stacktrace: at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.GetRelatedEndInternal(String relationshipName, String targetRoleName) 
at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.FindRelatedEntityKeysByForeignKeys(Dictionary`2& relatedEntities, Boolean useOriginalValues) 
at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.TakeSnapshotOfForeignKeys() 
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.PromoteKeyEntryInitialization(EntityEntry keyEntry, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, IExtendedDataRecord shadowValues, Boolean replacingEntry) 
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachSingleObject(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName) 
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity) 
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Attach(TEntity entity) 
at ... snip ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't you update the attached entity with the values of the unattached entity in stead of trying to swap them? You seem to cut some associations by that.

Comment: Thanks, yes - interestingly if I do exactly as you say (set each property of entryToUpdate to updatedEntry and then save instead of attaching) it works.  What I want to know, however, is why the attach does not work and to know that I want to know how to find out what the root cause was for this exception.  Surely since it threw the exception the framework must know - I just wish it had told me.

Comment: I think it is the detach that causes problems. I understand from the exception that the RelationshipManager tries to resolve associations of an object that is not tracked anymore.

Comment: Maybe - any idea how to find out the root cause though?  (the detach line does not throw it is the _set.Attach that throws but maybe the detach caused some object to become orphaned or something)

Comment: I have the same problem. Cannot figure out the root cause either.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a work-around than an actual solution...

I have been able to determine that the problem is related to attributes that are collections. I suspect that Linq may be trying to populate a null collection.

Inspecting the offending object, I've found I can work around the problem like this:

Old Code:

```
var myObject = db.MyObjectCollection.Find(x=>x.id = myId);
```

New Code

```
 var myCollection = db.MyObjectCollection.Where(x=>x.id = myId);
 if(myCollection != null && myCollection.Count() > 0){
     var myObject = myCollection.First();
 }
```

This resolves the error. However, the problem with this solution is that it only solves the problem in the single case that throws the error and there is no guarantee it won't crop up somewhere else. In fact, it has been a bit like playing Whack-Em-All as the error reappears in other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the error message I'm guessing that you are trying to attach something that has a relationship to some other object that is not tracked by the ObjectStateManager (i.e. possibly not an entity).